# Retraining Open Images pretrained Inception v3 model

Tags: dataset, tensorflow

Is there a way to retrain Open Images pretrained inception v3 model https://github.com/openimages/dataset?

Here is what I've tried:
 1. Inception approach https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception, but it produced an error "Tensor name "conv1/BatchNorm/beta" not found in checkpoint files /datavol/home/ec2-user/tensorflow/models/inception/inception-v3-model/inception-v3/model.ckpt", where model.ckpt is Open Images model checkpoint.
 2. Read tensorflow-for-poets tutorial, but it requires to have these files: classify_image_graph_def.pb,
imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt, and I have only model.ckpt and model.ckpt.meta.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: TensorFlow for Poets tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets.

Comment: For 1), are you loading the checkpoint that is compatible with the graph?

Comment: @Fake, how to make sure that my checkpoint is compatible with the graph?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed description available on TensorFlow site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

It describes how to retrain the Inception-v3 model to recognize the new classes according to applied images.

Comment: It seems the link you have provided is same as the tensorflow for poets tutorial.  how to obtain the 3 files equivalent to the ones asked in the question?